# How to use oracle like operator in JSTL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jstl

Following code I used

```
<sql:query dataSource="jdbc/crawl" var="rs">
    select * from vsites where site like %?%
    <sql:param value="${param.key}"/>
</sql:query>
```

But it throws exception

My url is: `http://localhost/c/2.jsp?key=math`

thanks

Comment: following exp i got: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
 select * from vsites where site like %?%
 
: ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
 select * from vsites where site like '%' || ? || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpaly you can use like:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE lower(question) LIKE '%${query}%';
```

Example :

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${dbsource}" var="question">                                                            
              SELECT * FROM question WHERE lower(question) LIKE '%${query}%';
 </sql:query>

 <c:forEach items="${question.rows}" var="q">
       <c:out value="${q.q_id}"/>,<c:out value="${q.question},<c:out value="${q.question}"/> 
 </c:forEach>
```

> `you can replace <c:out value="${q.value}"/> by simply ${q.value}`